# What's the difference between (function (x :< _)) = x and (function (x :_)) = x

Tags: haskell

What is the less than symbol used in the notation `x:<_`?
I know that `(function (x :< xs))=x`  would mean, a function that takes a string and gives the head of the string as output. Then I suppose `x:_` and `x:xs` in this function would be interchangeble, but im not familiar with the notation < in this expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:<` is just a constructor for some type in the same way `:` is for lists e.g.

```
data Stream a = a :< (Stream a)
```

in this case you could have a function to get the first item in the stream as

```
streamHead :: Stream a -> a
streamHead (a :< _) = a
```

Comment: A stream is just a cycle of types right? Like, say stream of 1, 2, 3. When im up to 3 and i call streamHead (3 <: xs) = 1.

Comment: No, a stream models an infinite sequence; notice there is no constructor to model an empty stream. It's possible for a cycle to be modeled with a stream (something like `let n = 1 :< (2 :< n)`), but not all streams are cyclical.

Comment: An example of a non-cyclical stream would be `fix $ \nats -> 0 :< fmap succ nats`